# Persist @OneToMany List

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to persist the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_father")
public class Father implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "tb_father_id_seq", sequenceName = "tb_father_id_seq")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "tb_father_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="father", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<Son> sons;

... Gets and Sets

}


@Entity
@Table(name="tb_son")
public class Son  implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "tb_son_id_seq", sequenceName = "tb_son_id_seq")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "tb_son_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Inject
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="father", referencedColumnName="id")
private Father father;


... Gets and Sets

}
```

Example:

```
Father father = new Father();
Son son = new Son();
...
father.getSons().add(son);
```

And in my FatherDAO

```
@Stateless
public class FatherDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
    public void persistFatherSons(Father father) throws ApplicationException {
        try {
            em.persist(father);
        } catch(Exception e) {
        ...
        }
    }

...

}
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_father
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tb_father_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
)

CREATE TABLE tb_son
(
   id integer NOT NULL,
   father integer,
   CONSTRAINT tb_son_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT fk41b1efcfa0ebdd8c FOREIGN KEY (father)
       REFERENCES tb_father (id) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

When running "em.persist (father)" only the father is saved in the database and not the Sons (List) .

Error now:

```
08:00:21,123 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http--10.36.1.49-8180-1) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff7f000101:-81b794d:5523b2cf:61, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@6bb7796b >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: error during managed flush
at  org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1486) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
...
```

Ready !!! The two entity ai was the example I created to demonstrate the problem that was going on here . What was missing in the example was a **Float** field. This field was **@Size** and this was causing the error.

Thankssss

Comment: I could not solve ... yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below change.

```
@Inject
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="father")
private Father father;
```

Comment: Can you paste the test case?